# How do I refactor a view to allow filtering of items bound to an observableArrayList inside a tornadofx app

Tags: kotlin, observable, tornadofx

I started with the gradle `hello-world` example found https://github.com:JetBrains/kotlin-examples.git and modified it to use TornadoFX.

This is an app that displays a list of items. You can add to the list, and the `RequestView` will automatically display all the items.

I have it working so that the items stored are bound to an `observableArrayList` but I now want to implement a filter using the `TextView` at the bottom. But, I'm struggling to understand whether this means I should create a new list which is managed internally in the `RequestView`, and filter from that, or how to do it.

```
package demo

import javafx.collections.FXCollections
import javafx.geometry.Pos
import javafx.scene.control.TextField
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight
import tornadofx.*

class helloWorldApp : App(HelloWorld::class) {
}

class HelloWorld : View() {

    override val root = VBox()

    var requestView: RequestView by singleAssign()
    var filterField: TextField by singleAssign()

    init {
        with(root) {
            requestView = RequestView()
            this += requestView
            filterField = TextField()
            this += filterField
        }

        requestView.items.add("Hi there")
        requestView.items.add("Another one")

    }

}

class RequestView() : View() {
    var items = FXCollections.observableArrayList<String>()

    override val root = listview(items) {
        cellFormat {
            graphic = cache {
                form {
                    fieldset {
                        label(it) {
                            alignment = Pos.CENTER_LEFT
                            style {
                                fontSize = 15.px
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.BOLD
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the build.gradle file, just in case it is helpful.

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2'
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}


apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'demo.helloWorldApp'

defaultTasks 'run'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

tasks.compileKotlin.kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"

dependencies {
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
  testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version"
  compile 'no.tornado:tornadofx:1.7.10'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion = "2.7"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `SortedFilteredList` which wraps an ObservableList and accepts a predicate which is used to discriminate the entries.

There is an unfortunate coupling between your two views, so you should consider firing an event instead, but here is a working solution with minimal changes to your example. I did move the data to a model, and cleaned up the ui code, as well as got rid of the `singleAssign` statements and applied some best practices to the builders :)

As you can see, the `SortedFilteredList` has a `filterWhen` function that will be called whenever the `textProperty()` of the textfield changes.

```
class HelloWorldApp : App(HelloWorld::class)

class HelloWorld : View() {
    val requestView: RequestView by inject()

    override val root = vbox {
        add(requestView)
        textfield {
            promptText = "Filter"
            requestView.data.filterWhen(textProperty()) { query, item ->
                item.contains(query, ignoreCase = true)
            }
        }
    }
}

class ItemsModel : ViewModel() {
    val items = FXCollections.observableArrayList<String>()

    fun addItem(item: String) = items.add(item)

    init {
        addItem("Hi there")
        addItem("Another one")
    }
}

class RequestView() : View() {
    val model: ItemsModel by inject()
    val data = SortedFilteredList(model.items)

    override val root = listview(data) {
        cellFormat {
            graphic = cache {
                form {
                    fieldset {
                        label(it) {
                            alignment = Pos.CENTER_LEFT
                            style {
                                fontSize = 15.px
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.BOLD
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```